# What are the maximum heights and weights of the PHB races?

Tags: dnd-5e, races

What are the maximum heights and weights for the races found in the *Player's Handbook*, including the subraces?

Comment: Do you own the players handbook, or have access to it?  Similarly, what about [this table](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=35) in the basic rules did you find unclear?  Are you looking to make a comparison to a previous edition of the game?  Your question could use some clarification to be more answerable.

Comment: Is there something you're trying to do with this information beyond just having it consolidated here? Right now, you're just asking us to read the book to you. But if you've got an issue or question you're trying to solve *with* that information - please ask that and you'll get a better response.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this stack does not exist to simply read the book to people.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I'm not sure that is all this question is. If it is asking about the rollable tables, it could be a calculation question as dice math can be difficult.

Comment: @ObliviousSage It doesn't exist to do so, but those questions [can still be asked](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/what-do-we-do-with-read-the-book-to-me-questions). At the moment, it's a list question with a finite list. If someone wants to do the work for OP, they can. If they don't, they can downvote and move on.

Answer (score 13):

### This truncated table shows the ranges for the races in the Basic Rules

*I didn't include the remainder of the races in the Player's Handbook because the table used to calculate those tables is not available in the [SRD](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/SRD-OGL_V1.1.pdf) and therefore cannot be published due to copyright.*

[image]

This table uses the Random Height and Weight table found in a number of rulebooks and [here in the Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#HeightandWeight). If you want to calculate the range for any other race, simply download a copy of [the spreadsheet I used](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12py5vMJhelg381yib4Q-eJVoFi11qMLN/view?usp=drivesdk) and enter the details for the race you want to know the range of ([copying the formulae down](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/fill-a-formula-down-into-adjacent-cells-041edfe2-05bc-40e6-b933-ef48c3f308c6) to the relevant row(s) if necessary).

If you are interested, here are the formulae that the spreadsheet uses:

- Minimum Height

  - Base Height + the number of dice (times 1, the minimum roll)
- Maximum Height

  - Base Height + the number of dice times the maximum roll on a die
- Minimum Weight

  - Base Weight + the number of height dice (times 1, the minimum roll) times the number of weight dice (times, 1 the minimum roll)
- Maximum Weight

  - Base Weight + the number of height dice times the maximum roll of a height die times the number of weight dice times the maximum roll of a weight die